# Unable to access Android app after deploying it in worklight Server 5.0.2.407

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I've developed a small application for testing whether the app works properly or not after deploying it in worklight server. I deployed the app and adapter file in worklight server in another machine and my web service war file in my localhost. When i test this in a browser, its properly fetching the data from the webservice. Even it is working on android phone browser. But its not fetching any data when i test it in android phone by deploying its apk file. In logcat its giving me this error,

"request time failed: java.net.SocketException : Address family not supported by protocol"

My Server version: 5.0.2.407 
Developed the app in the studio version : 5.0.6.20130311-0918

Pls help me to solve the problem. We dont have the recent Worklight server. So, trying to install the new app in older server version.

This is the info content of my logcat:

06-20 12:44:18.463: I/dalvikvm(415): Could not find method android.webkit.WebView., referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.

06-20 12:44:18.463: W/dalvikvm(415): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 529: Landroid/webkit/WebView;. (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;IZ)V

06-20 12:44:18.753: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{4403f778 com.Server/.Server}

06-20 12:44:18.783: I/CordovaLog(415): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)

06-20 12:44:18.803: I/CordovaLog(415): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false

06-20 12:44:18.963: I/CordovaWebView(415): Disabled addJavascriptInterface() bridge since Android version is old.

06-20 12:44:19.503: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.Server/.Server: 2080 ms (total 2080 ms)

06-20 12:44:30.552: I/Web Console(415): jquery  was called at file:///data/data/com.Server/files/www/default/js/jquery_1.7_min.js:4

06-20 12:44:33.483: I/Database(415): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467

06-20 12:44:34.053: I/Web Console(415): Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. at file:///data/data/com.Server/files/www/default/wlclient/js/cordova.js:1112

06-20 12:44:34.843: I/dalvikvm(415): Could not find method java.util.Calendar.getDisplayNames, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.Globalization.getDateNames

06-20 12:44:34.843: W/dalvikvm(415): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9874: Ljava/util/Calendar;.getDisplayNames (IILjava/util/Locale;)Ljava/util/Map;

06-20 12:44:34.853: I/dalvikvm(415): Could not find method java.util.Calendar.getDisplayNames, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.Globalization.getDateNames

06-20 12:44:34.853: W/dalvikvm(415): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9874: Ljava/util/Calendar;.getDisplayNames (IILjava/util/Locale;)Ljava/util/Map;

06-20 12:44:34.863: I/dalvikvm(415): Could not find method java.util.Calendar.getDisplayNames, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.Globalization.getDateNames

06-20 12:44:34.863: W/dalvikvm(415): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9874: Ljava/util/Calendar;.getDisplayNames (IILjava/util/Locale;)Ljava/util/Map;

06-20 12:44:34.863: I/dalvikvm(415): Could not find method java.util.Calendar.getDisplayNames, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.Globalization.getDateNames

06-20 12:44:34.863: W/dalvikvm(415): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9874: Ljava/util/Calendar;.getDisplayNames (IILjava/util/Locale;)Ljava/util/Map;

06-20 12:44:38.113: I/Web Console(415): jquery  was called at :4

06-20 12:45:54.934: I/java.net.Socket(342): www.google.com/74.125.235.52(80): java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out

06-20 12:46:08.009: I/java.net.Socket(342): www.google.com/74.125.235.52(80): java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out

06-20 12:49:04.162: I/java.net.Socket(342): www.google.com/74.125.235.51(80): java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out

06-20 12:49:17.184: I/java.net.Socket(342): www.google.com/74.125.235.51(80): java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will never work.

The communication protocol as well as entire authentication framework was changed in Worklight v5.0.0.**3**.

You cannot use a newer app created in Worklight 5.0.6 with this specific old Worklight Server version (5.0.0.**2**).

You will have to upgrade the server version.

Comment: thanks idan. But, how is it working properly with browser then and one more thing, as i'm not using any authentication framework in my app, any work arounds will make that server work ??

Comment: The error message you mentioned is not related to Worklight, you'll have to provide the full logcat log.

Comment: hi idan.. i updated the question with my logcat info data.. thanks in advance..:)

Comment: Only Worklight-related log there is "jquery was called at file:///data/data/com.Server/files/www/default/js/jquery_1.7_min.js:4" and it is not clear from it what is wrong... need more data about the app.

Comment: this app consists of only one page which authenticates the given name and password.. when we click the button, web service which is located in my system should be called which worklight server is unable to connect to.. as i told, its successfully working in browser

Comment: I don't know why or how this works for you. EVERYTHING is different in 506 compared to 5003...

Comment: and when i check for the android preview in google chrome, i'm getting this error in the console
--->

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) http://192.168.120.196/worklight/apps/services/api/Server/android/query
Request [/worklight/apps/services/api/Server/android/query] wlgap.android.js:1538
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://192.168.120.196/worklight/apps/services/api/Server/android/query
Request [/worklight/apps/services/api/Server/android/query] wlgap.android.js:1538

Comment: The 401 is expected. The 403 is not, and it's most likely due to authentication differences... @venkataharika, 5002 server will not work with 506 application.